# In Qt, how to use a timer to enable/disable a function?

Tags: c++, qt

Say I have a function work(), once it is called, I don't want it to be called in the next 5 seconds. 
Currently, I have designed some simple codes as:

```
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(resetflag()));
...
if(!flag)
{
    flag = true;
    work();
    timer.start();
}
...
void resetflag(){
  flag = flase;
}
```

My question is: 1.) How to make this thread safe?
                2.) Is there any simpler and elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Mark `resetFlag` as a slot and call it via signals. It will be thread-safe.

Comment: In my current implementation, it is already a slot, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know. You didn't provide SSCCE. You didn't show how you plan to use moltithreading there.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: Assuming it's **only** called via a signal.

Comment: Cant' you simply declare flag as volatile? If the code posted is the only one using flag, it should be enough to make it be thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be simpler to just keep a timestamp of the last time you called the function and update it when work is done:

```
//field
QElapsedTimer timeSinceLastCall;


//function
if(!timeSinceLastCall.isValid()||timeSinceLastCall.hasExpired(5*1000))
{
    timeSinceLastCall.restart();
    work();
}
```

however the function won't be thread safe (multiple threads can get into `work()`), you'll need some other way to exclude them such as:

```
//field
QElapsedTimer timeSinceLastCall;
QMutex mutex;


//function
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    if(timeSinceLastCall.isValid() && !timeSinceLastCall.hasExpired(5*1000))
        return;
    timeSinceLastCall.restart();
}
work();
```